# Trouble in search in Grocery CRUD library

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

While using search query through Grocery CRUD library in Codeigniter,search for  "0" value of a data in a table results in the full table. why?

```
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_table('listing');
$crud->field_type('SwimmingPool','dropdown',array('1'=>'Yes', '0'=>'No'));
$output = $crud->render();
```

Now searching in output of grocery_CRUD for the values of SwimmingPool = 0, results in the complete table (all values). While it works fine for SwimmingPool =1 and filter the results properly. I double checked the MySQL database table 'listing' and SwimmingPool has value 0 or 1 only. is this some kind of bug that search query results in the complete table if searched for 0. Any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug of grocery crud, interpreting 0 as null so it does not apply the search filter. I suggest filling a bug report at Grocery's bug tracker on github